# Faire des couloirs de

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire que de faire des couloirs de quelque chose? Dans l'article que je viens de lire, on dit:

> Cette mère s’est fait connaitre à force de faire des couloirs de l’ONIAM et de frapper à toutes les portes.

En voici le lien: https://fr.sputniknews.com/international/202011031044677897-enfants-tues-ou-handicapes-par-la-depakine-le-parcours-du-combattant-des-familles-de-victimes-video/

Comment: Je crois que 'des' est une coquille et devrait être 'les'

Answer (score 3):

L'expression utilisée en France est *faire **les** couloirs*.

Ici, couloirs correspond à cette définition du TLFi :

> − *Spéc. au plur.* Voisinage de la salle des séances d'une assemblée, où circulent les bruits officieux. *Bruits, intrigues de couloirs; les couloirs de la Chambre, du Palais de Justice.* Les combinaisons de couloirs et d'antichambre (*Doc. d'hist. contemp.*, 1852-1959, p. 59).

*Faire* signifie arpenter, passer du temps dans les locaux de l'organisme en question en vue de rencontrer des personnes et tenter d'obtenir ce que l'on recherche.

Je l'ai toujours entendu ou utilisé au pluriel, mais le singulier est rapporté comme sénégalisme dans *Les mots du patrimoine: le Sénégal* de Geneviève N'Diaye-Correard.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

L'expression normale serait « faire le couloir » ([internaute](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/998/faire-le-couloir/)).

Cela signifie frapper à toutes les portes dans des organismes, le plus souvent publics, dans le but de se faire entendre ou d'obtenir des avantages.